# How can I tell jQuery to use the newly generated href attribute (generated with '.attr')?

Tags: jquery

I'm modifying the content of a href attribute with jQuery:

```
$("a#scrolll").attr("href", "#" + $("li.matched").attr("id"));
```

`<a href="#">scroll</a>`

and the output looks like this:

`<a href="#menu-id-123">scroll</a>`

If I click the link I'm taken to the element with that ID.

Below that jQuery line, I have the following:

```
$("a#scrolll2").click(function() {
        $("a#scrolll").trigger("click");
});
```

With gives me something like this:

`mydomain/somestuff#`

So I think even if the `a#scrolll` link has now an ID in its href attribute, the jQuery code is is till thinking the attribute is the initial one ('#').

How can I tell jQuery to use the newly generated href attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$("a#scrolll2").live('click',function() {
        $("a#scrolll").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: try this $("#scrolll2").live('click',function() {
        $("#scrolll").trigger("click");
});

Answer (score 0):

I think `id` values of the **`<a>`** tags needs to be set as "scroll1" and "scroll2" respectively.